# Mouse slow proportionally to network usage

Tags: networking, performance

Under ANY network loading the Logitech mouse gets slow. At download speeds of as low as 50KB/s, clicks are "grabby," a click will pick up an object and any movement will move it around. At rates above 150KB/s, the mouse barely moves. Network loading from web browsing and torrent downloads affect the mouse, I haven't looked into it any further then that.

Computer:

- AMD Phenom 8450 (tri-core @ 2 ghz)
- Ram: 6 GB
- Dual monitors (HD TV using HDMI, and a Dell Monitor (Portrait mode) on analog.
- Logitech Wireless mouse/keyboard (using default/automatic Ubuntu driver)
  (Microsoft USB Mouse)
- Fast Ethernet connection

The wireless keyboard does not appear to be affected. Repeatable on 13.10 and 14.04 (Desktop).

Interestingly, when I add the Microsoft USB mouse, that mouse works fine. In fact, that Logitech mouse intermittently may work better (or not) when the second mouse is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect the network load itself is not the issue here. More likely, it's the network activity's effect on your HDD (as data is read and written to it). Try doing some intensive HDD activities, checking the mouse symptoms under load.

Writing a large file via dd is a simple solution. [Here's a succinct guide on how to do so](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/hdparm).

You could also watch process stats via `top` while you're seeing the undesirable behavior, to check if any processes are misbehaving (excessive RAM or CPU usage).